# App crashes when UIImageView.image is set 2-3 times

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

My app crashes when I set the image-property on a UIImageView three times in a row (sometimes two times is enough). A few times I've seen a memory warning before the app closes, but most of the times it just collapses. The app does not crash in the simulator, so I'm quite sure it is a memory problem.

Here's the code I use when setting the image property:

```
-(void)changeBgPictureTo:(UIImage *)img
{
    [self.backgroundImage setImage:img];
}
```

The UIImages is allocated with the `[UIImage imageWithData:]` method:

```
[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:type]]];
```

The image is set correctly the first two times, but crashes on the third time. It has nothing to do with a specific image file. I've tried with 10 different images and it makes no difference.

How do I make the UIImageView unload previous loaded images?

**EDIT:**
Okay, I've been asked for the whole code so here it goes:

I'm working with a class which looks like this:

```
@interface MyImage : NSObject
{
    UIImage* image;
    int imgId;
    NSArray* colors; //contains 'UIColor' objects.
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage* image;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* colors;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) int imgId;

-(id)initWithFileName:(NSString*)fileName withType:(NSString*)type andId:(int)imgId andColors:(NSArray*)colorArray;

@end
```

Here is the init implementation:

```
-(id)initWithFileName:(NSString*)fileName withType:(NSString*)type andId:(int)imageId andColors:(NSArray*)colorArray
{
     self = [super init];

     if (self)
     {
         self.colors = [NSArray arrayWithArray:colorArray]; 
         self.imgId = imageId;
         self.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:type]]];
     }   

return self;
```

}

I have a datacontroller which has a list of 'MyImage' objects which is added in a loop with this call:

```
[self.myImages addObject:[[MyImage alloc] initWithFileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"0000%d", i] withType:@"jpg" andId:i andColors:colors]];
```

I have 9 images which is named 00001.jpg, 00002.jpg, ....., 00008.jpg.

This data controller has a method like this:

```
-(MyImage *)getImageWithId:(int)imgId
{
    for (MyImage* img in self.myImages)
    {
        if (img.imgId == imgId)
            return img;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

The getImageWithId method is called like this:

```
-(void)btnPushed:(id)sender
{
     [self.delegate changeBgPictureTo:[self.imgDataController getImageWithId:((UIButton*)sender).tag]];    
}
```

The changeBgPictureTo method is the method which makes the setting of the image-property:

```
-(void)changeBgPictureTo:(MyImage *)img
{
    NSLog(@"Setting image: %d", img.imgId);
    [self.backgroundImage setImage:img.image];    
}
```

The log prints "Setting image: 0000X:" three times, but crashes shortly after the third print.

Comment: have you tried setting it to nil, before loading new image.. i mean imageView.image = nil;

Comment: Yes, it makes no difference. It still crashes :(

Comment: What do you see in the log when it crashes? What type of crash is occurring?

Comment: Nothing. It writes absolutely nothing. Sometimes the app crashes by closing and sending me to the homescreen. Most of the times it crashes by making the screen black with a small activity loader in the middle of the screen. After a few seconds it sends me to the lockscreen. It looks like a "light reboot" or something like that.

Comment: Please provide some more detailed code so that we can see the root cause of the issue

Comment: I've added more code as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of storing the UIImage object inside MyObject class,try storing only the filename of the file.

```
@interface MyImage : NSObject 
{
    NSString *fileName;//UIImage* image;
    int imgId;
    NSArray* colors; //contains 'UIColor' objects.
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *fileName;//@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage* image;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* colors;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) int imgId;

-(id)initWithFileName:(NSString*)fileName withType:(NSString*)type andId:(int)imgId andColors:(NSArray*)colorArray;
```

and implementation

```
-(id)initWithFileName:(NSString*)fileName withType:(NSString*)type andId:(int)imageId   andColors:(NSArray*)colorArray
{
     self = [super init];

     if (self)
     {
         self.colors = [NSArray arrayWithArray:colorArray]; 
         self.imgId = imageId;
         //self.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:type]]];
         self.fileName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:type]];
      }   
      return self;
 }
```

then in function

```
 -(void)changeBgPictureTo:(MyImage *)img   
 {
    NSLog(@"Setting image: %d", img.imgId);
    //[self.backgroundImage setImage:img.image];    
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[img fileName]];
    [self.backgroundImage setImage:img];
 }
```

Comment: You may also want to add the fix by @sky1224 to fix the memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

At least you should release those MyImage instances after adding to your image array.

```
[self.myImages addObject:[[MyImage alloc] initWithFileName:[NSString stringWithFormat...
```

This code should be -

```
MyImage* img = [[MyImage alloc] initWithFileName:[NSString stringWithFormat... 
[self.myImages addObject:img];
[img release];
```

OR use autorelease.

Your code should get the memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

try by using the below to get the image from the bundle

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourImageName.png" ofType:nil]];
```

Comment: can u tell me the size of the images

Comment: Between 300 KB and 450 KB. Nothing huge.

Comment: it may be some other problem, run the app in simulator with zombie enabled and execute the simulate memory warning.. let me know what happens

Comment: When I execute the simulate memory warning nothing happens. The log writes "Received memory warning.", but the app continues as nothing happened.

Comment: when u run the app connecting ur xcode, in the organizer u will have device logs- which will give the log report of all the threads & functions in the device. Check what it shows there while crashing

Comment: It does not create a device log when it crashes with black screen. I have crashed the app at least 10 times today, but there's no crash logs with todays date :/

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that when you receive a low memory warning you release a certain property and then try to use it, but you're working with nil?

Have you tried simulating a low memory warning in the simulator to see if it crashes? Hardware > Simulate Memory Warning

Comment: Yes, I have tried using Simulate Memory Warning. It doesn't look like it has anything to do with my crash.